# Including images with project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently working on a program atm which connects to a client to a server that I run on my PC, I need to have the ability when you open the program file it does what it does but also it needs to the put a image file to a certain location.

I am able to move the files etc but the problem is I need to have the photo embeded into the file so when the "file.exe" is ran it puts the file in "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\MagicalSoftware\cat.jpg" automatically.

If someone could explain to me how to embed said imagine in the file.exe and have it export that would be amazing. I'm completely new to c++ and Visual Studio so if you could explain like you're talking to an idiot that would be appricated.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed an arbitrary file into the resources of your EXE by adding a [Resource file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) to your project. Then you can access the resource data at runtime using `FindResource()`/`LoadResource()`/`LockResource()` and write the data to a file of your choosing on the PC using whatever API you want (`CreateFile()`/`WriteFile()`, `std::ofstream`, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Visual Studio, you can drag your image directly into your project:

[image]

You then need to create the resource header file which references your image so that it may be compiled into binary code along with your project. Here's a pretty straightforward guide to run you through the steps: 
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/resources.html